# X11 programming display interface

Tags: c, linux, x11

I am trying to connect dual display on Xserver. How can i find number of monitors connected in Linux through X11 programming?(I am not asked about screen)

Comment: Generally you start using a more higher level library. For example use gtk and within gtk use gdk for the questions you ask see more at: http://www.gtk.org/documentation.php

Comment: `man 3 xinerama` has all the info.

Comment: @n.m. These days you use XRandR

Answer (score 0):

Today the XRandR extension is used for this. There's a command line tool `xrandr` the gives access to all functions of the XRandR protocol. It's hence a good way to learn how to use XRandR, but also (its source code) an excellent guide in using the XRandR extension in your own programs.